# How to allow a Textfield trailingIcon clickable

Tags: material-ui

I tried to use Material-UI Textfield trailingIcon attribute to add an Icon, but I couldn't find a way to make the Icon clickable.

```
    <TextField
      outlined
      name="add name"
      className={styles.textField}
      placeholder={'Add Name')}  
      value={name}
      invalid={false}
      trailingIcon={{ icon: 'clear', tabIndex: -1 }}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      onClick={handleClick)}
    />
```

I would be happy to know is there any default way to make TextField trailingIcon click beside using Formik that kind of additional library.

Comment: material-ui textfield doesn't have trailingIcon attribute. are you sure you are using material-ui component?

Comment: It does show trailingIcon.

Comment: Exactly, I was trying to click on an SVG rather than a material UI component.

Answer (score 4):

The prop `trailingIcon` doesn't exist in the TextField component's API.

That aside here's an example of how this would be accomplished with `InputProps`. You can use onClick in conjunction with the IconButton component. Example found [here](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#filled-input-adornments) under "Text Field Adornments"

```
      <TextField
        id="filled-adornment-password"
        className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
        variant="filled"
        type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
        label="Password"
        value={values.password}
        onChange={handleChange('password')}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <IconButton
                edge="end"
                aria-label="Toggle password visibility"
                onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
              >
                {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
      />
```